# Fiddler is not capturing some commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, fiddler

I'm trying to check how Get-Mailbox of Office 365 is working in PowerShell. 
So I stared fiddler to capture it, but was surprised that fiddler is not capturing that command.
So I tried to check newer alternative for Get-Mailbox called Get-EXOMailbox and on that command fiddler is capturing fine. But actually I need them both , to compare. Have no idea how to make fiddler to capture Get-Mailbox command. 
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Fiddler is a HTTP(S) proxy. Are you sure the `Get-Mailbox` command uses a HTTP based protocol? Use Wireshark to check which connections and ports are used.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and it seems to be https , as wireshark can't decrypt https without sessions keys, so I can't see the data as plain text, but it's https.

Comment: Depending on how the command is implemented it may just ignore the system proxy settings. For an implementation provided by Microsoft this would be unusual but considering that Microsoft often just buys an existing implementation and relabels it to a MS product such a scenario is possible.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that API are HTTPs, so interesting what is going on there, Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The way Fiddler works is that it changes the current proxy settings to `localhost:8888` (by default) and then listens on this port to intercept the traffic.

On the other hand, behind the scenes, PowerShell uses .NET Framework's `System.Net.WebClient` to make web requests, and as strange as it sounds, this client doesn't respect the system-wide proxy settings by default. 

To intercept the traffic, you probably need to manually change the proxy settings used by PowerShell, e.g. as described here: http://woshub.com/using-powershell-behind-a-proxy/.

Comment: Well, how this comes with the fact that Get-EXOMailbox is cached but not Get-Mailbox ? Same powershell, same fiddler ?